# A question that crossed my mind

Tags: calculus

Please,I would like to ask if the set $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers can be considered as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2 $?

Comment: Yes in many ways

Comment: No, of course not. The elements in $\;\Bbb R\;$ are plain real numbers, whereas the elements in $\;\Bbb R^2\;$ are **not** numbers but *ordered pairs of real numbers*, and thus the sets are completely different as they contain completely different elements. Now, under some pretty well explained and **clearly** agreed on conditions and assumptions, in some specific cases we could think that $\;\Bbb R\subset\Bbb R^2\;$,  yet this is **not** the usual case unless otherwise stated.

Comment: Okay,I also thought in the same way,but can we consider that the elements of R as one dimensional vectors??

Comment: Yes, you can look at $\mathbb R$ as a one-dimensional vectorspace over $\mathbb R$. On your original question: sets like $\mathbb R\times\{0\}\subset\mathbb R^2$ are isomorphic **copies** of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Fifi Exactly what drhab said, and I'll add: that we can thing of elements in $\;\Bbb R\;$ as one-dimensional vectors does not mean $\;\Bbb R\subset\Bbb R^2\;$, and the above comment means that there are infinite copies of $\;\Bbb R\;$ inside $\;\Bbb R^2\;$ , and none is "better" in any reasonable way to any other. The first comment is wrong, imo, and it could easily lead beginners to think false things happen in this matter...

Comment: Okay,thank you very much for your help